# Building client authorisation for a multi tenant system

Tags: authorization

We have a web application that caters to multiple tenants.
Now there are multiple `direct` clients corresponding to these tenants but 1 client may 
work for multiple tenants.
Our current authorisation system works on client level but we had seen issues were
one client which was invoked by a software system belonging to tenant1 fetched database records
belonging to tenant2 and mutated it.
The flow was:

```
Tenant1 app -> Client -> Our web service
```

We are now planning to further have strict auth now where we ask our client to either:

- Pass tenant info in request which can't be mocked by other systems.
- Do auth on their end for all tenants.

Can someone help with any suggestions?

PS: Feel free to comment for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to  have Tenant Id in all the parent tables in the database. There will also be a table which maps users to Tenants (and roles). This could be one to many relation. Example User "A" may have admin role with Tenant 1. But may have different role with Tenant 2.
Once you have set up this, you will have a foundation where data can be fetched in the context of a Tenant (Tenant Id is a must parameter for all queries).
Additionally you can impose restrictions on Authentication. For example if a user outside Tenant 1 tries to access Tenant One website, you can block him/her.
Hope this helps!